# How to determine the most visible view position after the RecyclerView adapter data change?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I want to determine the most visible item in my RecyclerView and so I use the following method:

```
public int getMostVisibleIndex() {
        // try to figure which child is the most visible on screen

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager());

        mFirstVisibleIndex = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        mLastVisibleIndex = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

        // How do I use convertPreLayoutPositionToPostLayout() ?

        VisibleIndex mostVisible = null;
        if (mFirstVisibleIndex != -1|| mLastVisibleIndex != -1) {


            // if it's not the same
            if (mFirstVisibleIndex != mLastVisibleIndex) {
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) this.getLayoutManager();

                // get the visible rect of the first item
                Rect firstPercentageRect = new Rect();
                linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(mFirstVisibleIndex).getGlobalVisibleRect(firstPercentageRect);

                // get the visible rect of the last item
                Rect lastPercentageRect = new Rect();
                linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(mLastVisibleIndex).getGlobalVisibleRect(lastPercentageRect);

                // since we're on a horizontal list
                if (firstPercentageRect.width() > lastPercentageRect.width()) {
                    return mFirstVisibleIndex;
                } else {
                    return mLastVisibleIndex;
                }

            } else {
                return mFirstVisibleIndex;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

It works great, but after I change the data set, and call any `notify*Changed` methods in my adapter, if I try to use the above function, the item positions that `findFirstVisibleItemPosition` and `findLastVisibleItemPosition` return are wrong.

I noticed that they both use [getlayoutposition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getlayoutposition) behind the scenes, and I also noticed that on the documentation it says:

> If LayoutManager needs to call an external method that requires the adapter position of the item, it can use getAdapterPosition() or convertPreLayoutPositionToPostLayout(int).

It sounds as if `convertPreLayoutPositionToPostLayout` is EXACTLY what I'm looking for, but I have no idea how to access it from within a `RecyclerView`.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I can only have maximum 2 visible views at a time in recyclerview and 
I am using this method in `onScrolled` for always having the `mostVisibleItemPosition`
for playing video content when user scrolls.

So `getTop()` returns top position of this view relative to its parent and when user starts scrolling `firstView` is getting out of the screen and the `firstView.getTop()` will return minus value while `secondView.getTop()` is positive and when `secondView` top reaches nearly the center of the screen getting absolute value of `firstView.getTop()` we will determine how many pixels `firstView` top is above from parent view top and getting  `secondView.getTop()`  we will determine how many pixels `secondView` top is above parent bottom and this is where `mostVisibleItemPosition` will changed.

```
  private void detectMostVisibleItem() {
        int firstItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        int secondItemPosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        if (firstItemPosition == secondItemPosition) {
            mostVisibleItemPosition = firstItemPosition;
        } else {
            View firstView = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(firstItemPosition);
            View secondView = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(secondItemPosition);
            if (Math.abs(firstView.getTop()) <= Math.abs(secondView.getTop())) {
                if (mostVisibleItemPosition != firstItemPosition) {
                    mostVisibleItemPosition = firstItemPosition;
                 ...
                }
            } else {
                if (mostVisibleItemPosition != secondItemPosition) {
                    mostVisibleItemPosition = secondItemPosition;
                 ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would you be kind enough to explain why this will yield the correct results even after `notify*Changed` methods get called?